# Drawing a diagonal semicircle in OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl, draw

I'm trying to draw a diagonal semicircle. So far I've only been able to draw ones that begin and end on a horizontal or vertical axis, like this:

[image]

I've tried modifying the code to tilt the circle, but it doesn't work. Can someone please tell me where I've gone wrong, this is infuriating!

```
float theta, tanTheta, x, y, dx, dy;
int circle_points = 1000, radius = 70;

glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

    for(int i = 0; i < circle_points; i++)
    {
        dx = pts[1].x - pts[0].x;
        dy = pts[1].y - pts[0].y;

        tanTheta = tan(dy / dx);

        // get the inverse
        theta = atan(tanTheta);

        x = radius * cos(theta);
        y = radius * sin(theta);

        glVertex2f(x, y);
    }

glEnd();
```

Comment: Have you tried looping through a different range of values for `i`? What about adding a constant offset value to `theta`?

Comment: "I've tried modifying the code to tilt the circle, but it doesn't work" can you show us the original code and your modification?

Comment: Have you considered using [`atan2`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/atan2) instead of calculating the angle in two steps? It *"computes the arc tangent of y/x using the signs of arguments to determine the correct quadrant"*.

Comment: That seems to be a math/geometry, not a programming problem. Should be explained in every middle school math book.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your Question. In general, you should [edit] the Question to *clarify the Question*, but not to include an Answer within the Question. You should create your own Answer with the code you used to solve your problem, then accept it (the system may require a 48 hour delay prior to accepting your own answer). When you have solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](//stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to calculate the angle to the start point and the angle to the end point by `atan2`.
Interpolate the angle between the start angle and the end angle and draw a line along the corresponding points on the circe:

```
float ang_start, ang_end, theta, x, y;

ang_start = atan2( pts[0].y, pts[0].x );
ang_end   = atan2( pts[1].y, pts[1].x );
if ( ang_start > ang_end )
    ang_start -= 2.0f * M_PI;

glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);

for(int i = 0; i <= circle_points; i++)
{
    float w = (float)i / (float)circle_points;
    float theta = ang_start + w * ( ang_end - ang_start );

    x = radius * cos(theta);
    y = radius * sin(theta);

    glVertex2f(x, y);
}

glEnd();
```